# How do I create a realistic glossy effect in CSS/SVG?

Tags: css, svg

So say I have `<div>` and I want it to look like a shiny, matte surface like [this album cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp6Fr.jpg)

I can slap a `linear-gradient` on that div, no problem at all. But it just looks like a gradient - artificial. The shine is curved and unrealistic, there's no texture, it just looks fake.

So other than photoshop, how could I recreate this effect?

Comment: Vector based graphics are not ideally suited to creating fine textures. To produce something similar would require multiple layers and overlapping gradients. What you are asking for is not trivial. Can you provide similar, vector based, examples of what you are after? Perhaps some examples of what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get close using CSS gradients and filter: blur. Here's my example, which isn't quite there but might be the right direction:

```css
.matte{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
}
 .finish{
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(124,124,124,0.5) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(124,124,124,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(124,124,124,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 0.3;
   filter: blur(10px)
}
```

```html
<div class="matte">
  <div class="finish">
  
  </div>
</div>
```